# LLC convert design misunderstood

Tags: power-supply, power-electronics, switch-mode-power-supply, dc-dc-converter, resonance

The question is addressed  to those who have designed LLC converter.
As you you know during the design steps you come to graphs that looks like the uploaded one.
[image]

The intuitive view is when you operate at nominal input voltage the gain should be 1, and according to the graph all Q values 10% load to 100% load cross the gain of 1 into resonant freq.
In real design that is quite different operation freq is changing with load (stable input voltage). What could be the reason of that.

I am uploading some measurements of real LLC I have designed.
Pout = 500W, Out = 12V, Vin = 390V, Fr = 80kHz, Lr = 30 uH, Cr = 120nF, Lp = 190uH
Waveforms measured with 200W output.
Switching node and resonant current.
Gate voltage Q1 and Q2
[image]
[image]

As you can see operating frequency is above resonance and that affect the efficiency, because harder turn off ( you can see the oscillations )

Any ideas why this is happening ?